# How to get the field value and assign to the variable in python

Tags: odoo

I am using **openerp 6**.My `form` contains one `text box` and I need to get that value and assign it to a variable so to perform calculations and to return a result to store in a new `textbox`...

Comment: you have created form in OpenERP, isn't I?

Answer (score 4):

I have give .py file here. This will calculate square of the number

```
from osv import osv
from osv import fields
class test_base(osv.osv):
_name='test.base'

_columns={
    'first':fields.integer('Enter Number here'),
    'result':fields.integer('Display calclation result'),


    }
 def first_change(self, cr, uid, ids,first,context=None):

    r=first*first
    return {'value':{'result':r}}

test_base()
```

xml file is given here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>

   <record model="ir.ui.view" id="test_base_form">
       <field name="name">test.base.form</field>
           <field name="model">test.base</field>
           <field name="type">form</field>
           <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="best Base">
            <field name="first" on_change="first_change(first)"/>
            <field name="result"/>

              </form>
          </field>
    </record>
     <record model="ir.ui.view" id="test_base_tree">
       <field name="name">test.base.tree</field>
           <field name="model">test.base</field>
           <field name="type">tree</field>
           <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Test Base">
            <field name="first"/>
            <field name="result"/>

              </tree>
          </field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_test_seq">
        <field name="name">Test Base</field>
        <field name="res_model">test.base</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
    </record>

 <menuitem id="menu_test_base_main" name="Test Base">
    </menuitem>
<menuitem id="menu_test_base_sub" parent="menu_test_base_main" name="Square   number" action="action_test_seq">
    </menuitem>
</data>
    </openerp>
```

Comment: Hi friend, Did u find my solution useful ? if so mark my answer as correct answer. Thanks